# What does happen to the snippet below when I uncomment the move constructor A(A&&)?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

The snippet below seems to be all right, and I believe the declaration `A a(std::move(b).toA());` in `main()` invokes the implicitly declared move constructor for class `A`, as `A` doesn't have a user-defined copy constructor, it doesn't have a user-defined copy assignment operator, it doesn't have a user-defined move assignment operator, nor a user-defined destructor (see §12.8/9 N4140). However, when I uncomment the move constructor `A(A&&) { std::cout << "move A" << '\n'; }` below, I receive the `Illegal instruction` message. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/121919f0e6084fef). Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class A {
public:
//    A(const A&) { std::cout << "copy A" << '\n'; }
//    A(A&&) { std::cout << "move A" << '\n'; }
    A(std::unique_ptr<int>&& u_ptr) : u_ptr(std::move(u_ptr)) {}
    const int& getInt() { return *u_ptr; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> u_ptr;
};

class B {
public:
    B(int u_ptr) : u_ptr(new int(u_ptr)) {}
    A toA() && { return A(std::move(u_ptr)); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> u_ptr;
};

int main() {
    B b(-1);
    A a(std::move(b).toA());
    std::cout << a.getInt() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your move constructor definition is not doing what the implicitly defined one does — it does not move construct the `u_ptr` data member. So `a.u_ptr` is default constructed, and the internal `int*` is initialized to `nullptr`. The call to `a.getInt()` then attempts to dereference this `nullptr` leading to the crash.

Define your move constructor as below and your code will behave correctly

```
A(A&& other) : u_ptr(std::move(other.u_ptr)) { std::cout << "move A" << '\n'; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see now that the move constructor is called twice. That's what I was trying to verify. Can you explain why is it called twice? I thought it should be called three times.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Why three? There's one move construction when the return value of `std::move(b).toA()` is initialized, and a second one when that return value is used to construct `a`.